# Find SUM and MAX in custom aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plsql, plpgsql

I've been working recently with custom aggregate function.
In this custom aggregate, the first function, doesn't compute the sum and the max value correctly.
I'm using a composite type to return the sum and the max value.

I've tried with appending everything with the array, but it's not an efficient way to work

```
CREATE TYPE sum_max_complex AS (sum real, max_v real);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculateSum(sum_max_complex, real) RETURNS sum_max_complex AS $$
DECLARE 
   sumValue real := 0;
   max_v real := $2;
   output sum_max_complex;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '-------------------';
    RAISE NOTICE 'IL PRIMO VALORE DI INPUT E: % ... %',$1.sum,$1.max_v;
    RAISE NOTICE 'IL SECONDO VALORE DI INPUT E: %',$2;
    IF $2 IS NOT NULL THEN
      sumValue := calculateSumAggregate(sumValue,$2) + sumValue;
    ELSE
      sumValue := sumValue;
    END IF;
    max_v := searchmaximumvalue(max_v,$2);


    output.sum := sumValue;
    output.max_v := max_v;

    RAISE NOTICE '-------------------';
    RAISE NOTICE 'IL VALORE DI OUTPUT SONO: % ... %',output.sum,output.max_v;
    RETURN output;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addLaplacianNoiseSum(sum_max_complex) RETURNS real AS $$
DECLARE
   epsilon real := 0.005;
   sensivity real := $1.max_v;
   laplaceDistribution real;
BEGIN

   laplaceDistribution := generaterandomvalues(sensivity / (epsilon));

   RETURN  $1.sum + laplaceDistribution;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE AGGREGATE SUM_LAPLACE(real)
(
  SFUNC = calculateSum,
  STYPE = sum_max_complex,
  FINALFUNC = addLaplacianNoiseSum
);
```

In my table column, I have as values: 19,22,22.5,27.
It takes the correct value in the $2 parameter method, in the 1st function, but doesn't accumulate and sum every value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are ever adding to the values stored in the sum_max_complex type.  Here's a simplified example that shows approximately what you should do.  I don't know what calculateSumAggregate or generaterandomvalues do, so I wasn't able to reproduce those.

```
CREATE TYPE sum_max_complex AS (sum real, max_v real);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculateSum(sum_max_complex, real) RETURNS sum_max_complex AS $$
select ROW(
    $1.sum + coalesce($2, 0),
    greatest($1.max_v, $2)
)::sum_max_complex;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addLaplacianNoiseSum(sum_max_complex) RETURNS real AS $$
  select $1.sum + ($1.max_v/0.005);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

CREATE AGGREGATE SUM_LAPLACE(real)
(
  SFUNC = calculateSum,
  STYPE = sum_max_complex,
  FINALFUNC = addLaplacianNoiseSum,
  INITCOND = '(0, 0)'
);

with a as (select a from (values (19), (22), (22.5), (27)) v(a))
select sum_laplace(a) from a;
 sum_laplace
-------------
      5490.5
```